# Interior Points Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am confused about interior points. Basically, I think that if the set we are not working in doesn't contain irrational numbers, then the interior of the set is $\emptyset$.

$\left [ 0, \; 5\right ]$ has a non-empty interior because we are working the Reals.

However, for $\left \{ r \in Z \; | \; r > 1 \right \}$ has an interior = empty set. This is because in any neighborhood of an $r$ in the set, it will contain an irrational number. Since irrational numbers aren't in the set, the interior is the empty set.

So, if we aren't working the Reals, our interior is always going to be the empty set??

Comment: It mainly depends on the Topology you choose. If you take the standard topology on such metric spaces and define as "open" on Balls/Spheres of radius $\epsilon$ (iow $B_\epsilon(x_0)=\{x\in X|d_{std}(x,x_0)<\epsilon \}$) then yes, you are right. Else one could define other topologies (for example the discrete topology of $\mathbb{Q}$) and then the interior would not be the empty set :)

Comment: You should make your sentence "working the real" more precise. It does not depend on the set, but on the topology you put on it.

Comment: @b00nheT I'm a very novice math person and am using an intro analysis text. That went over my head simply because I do not know what a Topology is yet.

Comment: well... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology#Topologies_on_sets That's what one would call a Topology on a set. Once the three axioms/properties are fulfilled you have a Topology, an element in the topology is called *open*.(For example, in the "counterexample" I was referring to in my above answer, the discrete topology is nothing else than **all** possible subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ hence even single points are in the topology, hence we refer as them as *open*).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an answer that has to do with the set of real numbers $\mathbb R$
provided with what is called "Euclidean Topology".

A point $x$ of a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ is *internal* if and only if there is an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $x\in (a,b)$ and $(a,b)\subseteq A$. The *interior* of $A$, $int(A)$, is the set of all its internal points. Thus $int([0,5])=(0,5)$, because neither for $0$ nor for $5$ you can find an open interval $(a,b)$ with the required property, but for all the other points of $[0,5]$ you can.

On the other end $int(\mathbb Z)=\emptyset$ because for any $z\in\mathbb Z $, any $(a,b)$ such that $z \in (a,b)$ contains real numbers other than $z$.

I hope this is clarifying enough.